# Detect which GameObject Touched?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 `Game Objects`. These 3 Game Objects are my **right** , **up** and **left** buttons.

But I have no idea to control and check which of them clicked to action on **player** !

> **Note** : I can do this by creating special C# for each of game objects
>   by using OnMouseDown Method but I want do this in one Script file
>   attached to player .

[image]

and this is one of my `Game Objects` for Control Player

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note : I can do this by creating special C# for each of game objects
>   by using OnmouseDown Method but i want do this in one Script file
>   attached to player .

This shouldn't be a problem at-all. You can have two scripts communicate with each other.

**Method 1**:

Notify the `PlayerController` script when there is a click action from other script.

Attach to each GameObject to detect click on. It sends the GameObject that was clicked to your `PlayerController` script.

```
public class ClickDetector: MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerController playerController;

    void Start()
    {
        playerController = GameObject.Find("GameObjectPlayerControlIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //Notify our PlayerController script that there was a click
        playerController.OnGameObjectClicked(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Add this to your `PlayerController` script. It receives the GameObject that was clicked. You can compare with the GameObject `name` or `tag`. I suggest you go with a `tag`.

```
public class PlayerController: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnGameObjectClicked(GameObject objClicked)
    {
        Debug.Log("There was a click from: "+objClicked.name);
        if (objClicked.CompareTag("right"))
        {
            //Your code
        }
        else if (objClicked.CompareTag("left"))
        {
            //Your code
        }
        else if (objClicked.CompareTag("up"))
        {
            //Your code
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2**:

Do everything in one script (`PlayerController`).

You can use a `raycast`. I suggest you use `tag` to compare which gameobject is clicked. Create 3 tags(`right`,`left` and `up`) from the Editor and put each GameObject to the right `tag`. If you don't want to use tag, you can replace the `if (rayCastHit.collider.CompareTag("up"))` with `if (rayCastHit.collider.name=="up")`.

```
void Update()
{
    //Check if Mouse Button is pressed
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //Raycast from mouse cursor pos
        RaycastHit rayCastHit;
        Ray rayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(rayCast, out rayCastHit))
        {
            if (rayCastHit.collider.CompareTag("right"))
            {
                //Your code
            }
            else if (rayCastHit.collider.CompareTag("left"))
            {
                //Your code
            }
            else if (rayCastHit.collider.CompareTag("up"))
            {
                //Your code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

After updating your question, *you need to attach a collider to your GameObjects for raycast to work. Attach **Box Collider 2D** to each of the 3 GameObjects.*

Also, since this is a 2D sprite, The code for **Method 2** changes a little bit:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Vector2 ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, Vector2.zero);
    if (rayHit)
    {
        if (rayHit.collider.CompareTag("up"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, from what you are doing, it looks like you need a [Virtual JoyStick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGYObojmkO4) and you are current doing it wrong. The current solution should work for you but the right way to do this is with the UI system (`Image` component).

Comment: I used your **Method 2**  , i define new tags for my game object and i copied your code inside my PlayerController Script file that attached to my player . when i click on right left and up game object nothing happened / i write a Debug.Log inside each of conditions for check tags

Comment: This is really simple. You are doing something wrong if **both** method did not work for you.  Please select one of the GameObjects you want to detect click on. Post a screenshot of it and what the components attached to it look like.

Comment: I have 3 Game Object . the tag for these 3 Game Objects are right , left and up. i copied your code into update method of PlayerController Script . and i Attached this Script file to Player . i put Debug.Log to test but in consol i have't any Log

Comment: I get it the first time you said. I ask for you to select **one** of those 3 GameObjecst, take a screenshot of it and upload it to your question. I want to see what components are attached to them.

Comment: Ok . I uploded it

Comment: Read the Edit in my answer to see your problem.

Comment: ok i attached Box Collider 2D on My 3 Game Objects And Updated Script But problem not solved . i dont need creat a complete virtual joystick but i want these 3 simple buttons only . if this work fine my problem will be solved

Comment: It's fine if you don't want to use a visual joystick. Again, you are doing something else wrong. I can't tell what that thing is. Try method 1 again since you added a collider. If that doesn't work, upload your project somewhere then provide a link here. I will check what's wrong with it.

Comment: It work fine now But i have Another problem . when i click Game Object it effect for one time and when i click and down the mouse button it not different by one click . In all cases of click or down the click button it effect on player for one time like 0.1 second and the release player . i wanna until the click button down player go

Comment: Which method is this?

Comment: if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Vector2 ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, Vector2.zero);
    if (rayHit)
    {
        if (rayHit.collider.CompareTag("up"))
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: Replace `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` with `GetMouseButton`. It should now always detect while the mouse button is held down.

Comment: Thanks All Problem Solved